# select conditional records on first and remaining are second in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have three column in mysql table

1. id
2. pubdate
3. status

i want to show record in below order

firstly shown those record which has

```
pubdate >=currdate() and status=1 and order by pubdate ASC
```

and then all remaining record in table with no any condition.

Please help for mysql query

Comment: Did you try anything

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with:

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pubdate>=CURDATE() AND status=1 ORDER BY pubdate ASC) AS a
      UNION all
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pubdate<CURDATE() OR status!=1) AS b;
```

Comment: i used it but it not showing first result record in  ORDER BY pubdate .

Answer (score 0):

Give some weight when conditions are met, and use that in ORDER BY:

```
SELECT *,
    IF(pubdate >= CURRENT_DATE AND status = 1, 10, 0) weight
FROM
    thetable
ORDER BY weight DESC, pubdate ASC
```